# What's the difference bw template class and instantion?

Tags: c++

I recently come up with the following pic explaining the c++ header's content.
[image: C++ IO Headers]

here to each class template, instantion is attached, what's the difference bw both of them and what's the advantage of having the former.

Comment: The same reason why we have `std::string` rather than `std::basic_string<char>`. All of these classes are templated to allow extreme flexibility, but there are also special typenames to simplify usage in most common use-cases.

Comment: The template defines a family of classes, parameterised on the template parameters.   An instantiation (as distinct from your misspelling as "instantion") is one class in that family, corresponding to a specific set of template parameters.   The advantage of the template is generality and genericity - for example, a template can be written which works for ANY character type, instantiated for different character types, and work correctly for all of them.  This avoids a need to hand-write a separate class to deal with the same thing on every possible character type.

Answer (score 2):

When you instantiate a normal class, you get the objects (or instances) of that class.

```
class Normal 
{
};

Normal Na, Nb; //Na and Nb are instances of the Normal class
```

When you instantiate a class template, you get classes of the type you have used as a template parameter.

Simple example:

```
template<typename T>
class PodTemplate { 
  T a;
}

typedef PodTemplate<int> intClass; //variable `a` in intClass is an int, as the template is instantiated with `typename = int`
typedef PodTemplate<float> floatClass; //variable `a` in  floatClass is an float, as the template is instantiated with `typename = float`
```

Similarly, in the picture you have shown, there are templates and instantiations of those templates which produce classes.

For example, consider the `basic_istream` class template:

```
template <typename charT, typename traits = char_traits<charT> >
  class basic_istream;
```

The instantiation of the above template with `typename = char` gives us the `istream` class.

```
typedef basic_istream<char> istream;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is explained quite well in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template). Anyway, you instantiate a template by providing the template arguments. For example:

```
template<
    class CharT,
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>
> class basic_stringstream;
```

is a template class that accepts 3 template arguments (2 of them have default values), while `basic_stringstream<char>` is a template instantiation with template argument `char`, and has an alias name (typedef) `stringstream`.

Comment: `basic_stringstream<char>` is a template instantiation with template argument**s** `char`, `std::char_traits<char>`, `std::allocator<char>`